# How to set the style of specific cells of a PrimeFaces panelGrid with layout=tabular

Tags: css, primefaces, cell, panelgrid

In GitHub issue [PanelGrid: No way to manage style or identifiers of panelgrid cells except for tabular mode #5840](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5840), says it is possible to do it but doesn't say how.

I want to "hide" some cells. I have partially solved the problem using `p:row` and `p:column`; but those components don't work well inside a `p:wizard`. So I was wondering if there is another way to do it. Right now, I'm only hiding the cell content, but I'd also like to remove the padding and borders from the generated `td`.

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me how to set the style of specific cells without using `p:row` and `p:column`.

**EDITED ON 11/15/22**

Following the advice here is some code:

```
<p:panelGrid
    columns="2"
    columnClasses="xs-width-fit-content,xs-width-100"
    styleClass="xs-width-100">
    ...
    <h:panelGroup
        id="otraPaginaPanelDetalleWritingLabelGroup"
        style="#{usuario22.writingGridOtraPaginaVisible ? 'visibility: visible' : 'display: none'}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup
        id="otraPaginaPanelDetalleWritingFieldGroup"
        style="#{usuario22.writingGridOtraPaginaVisible ? 'visibility: visible' : 'display: none'}">
        ...
    </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</p:panelGrid>
```

The `p:panelGrid` has 2 columns, one for labels, etc, and other for input fields, etc. Each column contains a single `h:panelGroup`.
Each pair of consecutive panelGroups would be a "row"; such "rows" are shown and hidden dynamically using AJAX.
When the panelGroups of a "row" are hidden, I would like to change the style of their containing `td`, to set padding and borders to 0.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question comes down to styling **empty** cells. You can use the [`:empty` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) to do so. You want to override the theme rule for panel cells `body .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell`, so you want to use custom CSS like:

```css
html body .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell:empty {
    // your properties
}
```

If you want to style certain cells containing certain content, you can use the [`:has` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) to select those cells. For example:

```html
<p:panelGrid ...>
    <p:column>
        <div class="myClass">
            ...
        </div>
    </p:column>
</p:panelGrid>
```

```css
html body .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell:has(.myClass) {
    // your properties
}
```

See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: Thanks again Jasper. I guess the :has selector can help me solve the problem. I updated the original post and added some code. I think that was your advice. Please take a look.

Comment: Jasper, following your tip I could solve my problem using the :has() and :not() pseudo-classes. I posted and answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Following Jasper's tip I could solve my problem using the `:has()` and `:not()` pseudo-classes.

First I changed the panel groups. Now they look like this:

```
<h:panelGroup
    id="otraPaginaPanelDetalleWritingLabelGroup"
    styleClass="xs-concealable-panel-group #{usuario22.writingGridOtraPaginaVisible ? 'xs-visible-panel-group' : 'xs-invisible-panel-group'}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup
    id="otraPaginaPanelDetalleWritingFieldGroup"
    styleClass="xs-concealable-panel-group #{usuario22.writingGridOtraPaginaVisible ? 'xs-visible-panel-group' : 'xs-invisible-panel-group'}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

I then added the following rules to the stylesheet:

```
.xs-visible-panel-group {
    visibility: visible;
}
.xs-invisible-panel-group {
    display: none;
}
html body .ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell:has(.xs-concealable-panel-group):not(:has(.xs-visible-panel-group)) {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The last rule applies to a cell (td) containing components with class `xs-concealable-panel-group` that do not contain components with class `xs-visible-panel-group`. This rule might seem more complicated than it needs to be but I am using a special code generator and using only `:has(.xs-invisible-panel-group)` was not enough.

I tested the solution with Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera. It doesn't work in Firefox 107.0. It works just fine with the others.